# Cassandra PHP - check if given timeuuid string is a valid timeuuid

Tags: php, cassandra, timeuuid

How can I check if a given timeuuid i.e. fa6e9e80-299c-11e7-98d8-f7a8744353f3 is a valid timeuuid before query?

using a slighty different, yet still right format timeuuid: fa6e9e80-299c-11e7-98d8-f7a8744353av results in an error:

```
object(Cassandra\Exception\InvalidSyntaxException)#199 (7) { ["message":protected]=> string(54) "line 1:103 mismatched character 'v' expecting set null"
```

Cassandra PHP driver documentation does not seem to offer a valid function to check. ( https://datastax.github.io/php-driver/api/Cassandra/ )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Check the version of the uuid using `version()` method. if 1 then it's timeuuid.**

https://datastax.github.io/php-driver/api/Cassandra/interface.UuidInterface/#method-version

Comment: Works somehow at  least. I just need to check if it throws a exception on construct of timeuuid
`new Cassandra\Uuid($timeuuid);`
this will through an invalidArgumentException, if I try to initate it.
There does not seem to be a proper way to check if it is infact a proper timeuuid in foresight.